# If $f:[0,1]\to R$ is an absolutely continuous function such that $f(x) = \int_0^1 \min(x,y)g(y)dy$ for $g\in L^1([0,1],R)$ then $f'(x)=\int_x^1g(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from a past exam:

> Let $g \in L^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $h :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
>
> 1. If $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous and satisfies $f'(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.
> 2. Now suppose that
>    \begin{equation}
>    f(x) := \int_0^1 \mathrm{min}(x,y) \, g(y) \, dy.
>    \end{equation}
>    Show $f'(x) = \int_x^1 g(y) \, dy$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.

I have only been able to prove part 2. if $g$ is continuous (because $f(x) = \int_0^x y g(y) \, dy + x \int_x^1  g(y) \, dy$. If $g$ is continuous, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = xg(x) + \int_x^1 g(y) \, dy + x(-g(x)) = \int_x^1 g(y) \, dy.)
\end{equation}
I'm not sure how to generalize this for a $g \in L^1$ that is not continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\phi$ is integrable, then $\int _x^{1} \phi (y)dy$ is absolutely continuous,  differentiable a.e. and its derivative equlas $\phi$ a.e.. Hence, (following your argument) $f'(x)=\int_x^{1}g(y)dy$ a.e..  Since both sides of this equation are continuous, equality holds at every point.